# Adwords Script Scheduling by Adwords API

Tags: google-ads-api

Is there a way by which i can control,that is schedule, run or pause the adwords Script using Adwords API.

My requirement is that i want to run some task through adwords API and want to make sure that whenever my task is running adwords script should not make any change. And as soon as the task is over (which may take days), i want to resume the script.

Currently i am maintaining this by disabling the script manually before running and i want to automate this that is disable script for account before running and resuming it as the task completes.

**UPDATE:**
I would also like to do the same thing for automated rules.

Answer (score 3):

you could do this through the Google Spreadsheet API:

- Create an spreadsheet
- When the AdWords API is running, it can write "running" in cell A1
- When the AdWords API finishes running, it can delete this value

And at AdWords Script side:
- When the AdWords Script starts running, it can read this cell, and stop running IF value in cell A1 is "running".

Hope you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

You can't schedule scripts / rules with AdWords API.

One thing you could do for Scripts though - put a file in Google Drive that'll serve as a lock:

```
BIG_TASK {
  Drive.putFile("lock")
  doThings();
  Drive.removeFile("lock")
}

SCRIPT {
  if (Drive.fileExists("lock")) {
    return;
  }
  doOtherThings();
}
```

No easy answer for rules though.