# Running or Scheduling an Adwords Script by Google Ads API

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm trying to execute (or schedule) an Adwords Script for Account Auditing.

I need to do this programmatically from my own software.

Is it possible to connect to a given account, schedule or run a specific script and then fetch the results?

I haven't found anything in the documentation, first time working with Google Ads API tho.

Most related post I've found is this one: [Adwords Script Scheduling by Adwords API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219274/adwords-script-scheduling-by-adwords-api)

But he is asking about the deprecated version of the API and he has a different and more specific need than I do.

I just need to schedule/run/create a script for a Google Adwords account programmatically, so I don't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to be able to do this too, but as far as I can tell, the answer is no. I don't see any method in the Ads API for this, and [this forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-scripts/iKBts0ojnYk) states, "It is still currently not possible to remotely trigger AdWords Scripts from another script." The post is a couple of years old, but appears to still hold.